# React Native Separate View Component Scrollable with FlatList?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to scroll a separate component with a FlatList?

```
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>Some component outside of FlatList</Text>
    <Text>Porfile Information Above FlatList</Text>
    <Text>How to scroll with flatlist</Text>
  </View>

  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <View>
        <Text>a bunch of list that will scroll</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
<View>
```

So if you render this entire component, there's a section above the FlatList, and it'll just stay there while only the FlatList is scrollable.

How do you make it so the top section can scroll with the FlatList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either put you component inside the `ListHeaderComponent` prop provided by the FlatList like:

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
            <Text>a bunch of list that will scroll</Text>
        </View>
    )}
    ListHeaderComponent={
       <View>
          <Text>Some component outside of FlatList</Text>
          <Text>Porfile Information Above FlatList</Text>
          <Text>How to scroll with flatlist</Text>
       </View>
    }/>
```

Or put everything inside a `ScrollView`, remember to put a View around the `FlatList` or else the `FlatList` scroll may not work:

```
<ScrollView>
    <View>
      <Text>Some component outside of FlatList</Text>
      <Text>Porfile Information Above FlatList</Text>
      <Text>How to scroll with flatlist</Text>
   </View>
   <View>
        <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View>
                    <Text>a bunch of list that will scroll</Text>
                </View>
         )}/>
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Second solution doesnt work, error "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews" shows its teeth.